# Facebook scores without publish_actions

Tags: facebook

I am developing a game with Unity and now trying to implement Facebook support so players can invite each other and challenge.

How to save player scores?

I found Facebook Scores API and it looks fine, but upload a score requires 'publish_actions' permissions. It looks okay too, but many games, like Candy Crush Saga for example, save player scores without asking for 'publish_actions'. How they do that?

I am even have just tested Candy Crush on fresh iOS device & Facebook account, and right, it asks me only for a few read permissions, and then pushing my scores so I can see it from other account!

Please tell me how it is implemented?

Comment: They don't use the Facebook score api

Comment: Looks like you are right, they are using custom servers for this. Okay, so I need to do the same and setup a server. I think it will be enough to use PHP with database for the development time, but is it enough for release and a lot of players? I am not too familiar with network and web technologies, so please suggest me what is the best technology for that? I mean server side.

Comment: There is no single one technology that would be “the best” for this. PHP and a MySQL database will do fine for the beginning. And when – or if – your app gets so successful that a single web server can’t handle it any more, put it into the cloud.